# How to write vendor loaded to class with an object and accessible in every class methods in Cake php?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How to write vendor loaded to class with an object  and accessible in every class methods ?

```
App::import('Vendor', 'facebook', array('file' => 'facebook/facebook.php'));
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => XXXXXXXXX,
      'secret' => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
    ));


class test_controller {

 function A() {
    $facebook->showUser() 
 }
 function B() {
    $facebook->showUser();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

initialize it in bootstrap.php and there ya go.

Comment: Or if you really want to be fancy, create your own class, put it in `libs` and then import/initialize that class from bootstrap.

Comment: it doesnt hurt to accept responses once in a while ;) It may improve the quality of help you receive.

Comment: Thanks .. For a single file and it will be component file also, then how will write it ?

Comment: Component file? I thought you wanted a class that was available throughout the application?